# Invoking a function before it is defined is ok if inside exports

Tags: javascript

The following fails with `ReferenceError: f1 is not defined`
:

```
f1();
f1 = () => { console.log("f1"); }
```

But the following works:

```
exports.x = () => {
  f1();
}

f1 = () => { console.log("f1"); }
```

What's the explanation for the second situation?

Comment: You're not actually invoking `f1` in the second example - you're exporting a function that will call it when called (by which time it *will* be defined).

Comment: It has nothing to do with `exports`, it is just the order of execution, in the second example, `f1` is not called before it is defined.

Comment: Make sure to use `let`/`const`/`var`, instead of assigning to an undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the function is being called before it is defined, that's why the error occurs:

```
f1(); // <- function is called before the function expression is evaluated
f1 = () => { console.log("f1"); }
```

In the second case the function is not called at all, instead it may be called in future by the module consumer.

```
exports.x = () => {
  f1(); // <- it will be called only if a module consumer will execute the module as a function
}

f1 = () => { console.log("f1"); }
```

In order to call the module as a function, the module consumer will have to import the module. When a module is imported, all the module code is evaluated (including our function expression). Therefore, by the time the module consumer calls the module as a function, the function expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any undeclared variable inside a function it will not throw error.

In your above second example the `exports.x` is not called so there is no error. If you will call that it will throw error.

An example is below

```js
function test(){
  console.log(x); //x is not defined still no error.
}
```

Now see what will happen when we call the function.

```js
function test(){
  console.log(x);
}
test();
```